# How to avoid race conditions when opening a file after creating a directory?

Tags: python, filesystems, race-condition

Consider this code:

```
os.mkdir('foo')
open('foo/bar.txt')
```

I tried this:

```
try:
    os.makedir('foo')
except OSError, e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
open('foo/bar.txt')
```

and this:

```
try:
    open('foo/bar.txt')
except IOError:
    os.makedir('foo')
    open('foo/bar.txt')
```

But in both cases, we still end up with a race condition.  Been thinking about this for a little while and I can't figure out a way to get rid of it.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: I think it depends on what you want to do if the file cannot be opened for writing.  Do you want to go back and try another filename, or do you want to just give up and throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

There is no race condition, you just need to do:

```
os.mkdir('foo')
open('foo/bar.txt', 'w')
```

because default is read mode (and there is no file)

Comment: His concern is that in between the `mkdir` and `open` calls, some other process could create the file, so the `open` would fail.

Comment: @JohnGordon he didn't mention that. It is not exactly race condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a directory and a file at the same time. That is impossible, so in that sense you'll always have a race condition.

However you can create another directory and file, i.e `baz/bar.txt`. After ensuring this file exist, you can do an atomic operation renaming `baz` to `foo`,  which then instantly will make `foo/bar.txt` come into existence. Does that satisfy your need to avoiding race conditions?

If not, you need to further exemplify what you mean with race conditions in your particular case, and what you want to avoid.